# How to change hover to click in jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onhover

I am using the following code (which I found elsewhere and am trying to modify to suit my needs) to create a div that slides from the right side onto my screen. How would I go about making it slide out when I click instead of hover? Thanks, in advance for your help.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#introbutton').hover(function() {
        $('#intro-container').stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
    });

    jQuery('#introbutton').hover(function() {
        // Do nothing
    }, function() {

        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('#intro-container').animate({
            left: '100%'
        }, 800);

    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of using

```
 
 $('#introbutton').hover(function(){})
```

use

```
 
  $('#introbutton').click(function(){})
```

Of course, you have to realize that unlike *hover*, which returns back to its previous state, the div won't return back to its original state after the *click* function has run. You might want to factor that into the overall solution. 
 
Hope this helps.

#### Edit

This code snippet resolves all the problem

```
 
var is_show = true;
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#introbutton").click(function(){return runFunction();});    
  });
});


function runFunction(){
    if (is_show){ //show div
        is_show = false;
        $('#intro-container').animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);       
    }
    else{ //hide div
        is_show = true;
        $('#intro-container').animate({
            'left': '100%'
        }, 800);         
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so do you mean that it's not possible to use the code I am using to make it return on a second click?

Comment: well, you can define 2 functions, and then set a variable to **true/false**; when first click is made, you can set the variable to true, and then execute the first function; once it's clicked again, set the variable to false, and execute the second function. I think that should work.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very proficient in javascript/jquery so I don't really understand what you mean. Secondly I can't even get it to work by changing the hover to click. it totally breaks it then. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have 2 questions: **1.** Does that code you pasted above currently work? **2.** What element has this id **introbutton** ?

Comment: answer to #1. Yes it works.
answer to #2. Basically what I have is a div that slides out onto the screen. I also have a standard html link which has the id "introbutton" : <a href="#" id="introbutton">Introduction</a>

Comment: I popped it in a jsfiddle to show you how it works.
[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/NY2kM/)

Comment: If I understand your question properly, http://jsfiddle.net/NY2kM/4/ should resolve the problem you are having. Let me know if it did.

Comment: We're getting much closer. The only issue yet is that if I click a third time it doesn't "reopen" it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NY2kM/11/ works perfectly. After testing it and confirming, do upvote my answer, and if possible, mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've marked it as resolved. I'd love to give you an upvote but I apparently need more reputation points...sorry about that.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using on.() i.e.

```
$('#introbutton').on('click', function() {
    // do whatever here
});
```

**Edit**

```
$('#introbutton').on('click',function(){
    $('#intro-container').stop(true, false).animate({'left': '0px'}, 900);
});
```

​You could also use click as per TheSmose as its the "shortcut method" to on()- but keep in mind

> .on() is the recommended way to do all your event binding as of jQuery
>   1.7. It rolls all the functionality of both .bind() and .live() into one function that alters behavior as you pass it different parameters.

Comment: alternatively: `$('#introbutton').click(function(){`

Comment: Braunson,
Your suggestion works except that I need to figure out how to make it slide back to left: 100%; on a second click. any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You could then use the toggle() :)